# Create Relationship between (not yet) existing nodes

Tags: neo4j

I'm trying to ingest data from Kafka to Neo4j via the `neo4j-stream` plugin.
Currently we are experimenting with the `CUD` strategy.

I wonder how we should deal with interconnected data.
Let's assume we stream 100 persons from Kafka to Neo4j.
When `person(id:1)` has a relationship `is_friends_with` with `person(id:50)` we can not create this relationship until the node for `person(id:50)` is created.

However, we have no control about the order of how the events are coming from Kafka.

So when the person data arrives, we would create the following CUD data:

- create node for `person(id:1)`
- create relationship  `is_friends_with(person1, person50)`.
- ...
- create node for `person(id:50)`

Unsurprisingly, when we ingest the events in this order the relationship is missing.

How can we deal with this?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a typical case to use MERGE.

Every time you have a relationship (which has start and end nodes) you do

```
MERGE (n:Person {id:foo})
MERGE (m:Person {id:bar})
MERGE (n)-[:is_friends_with]-(m)
```

The merge for the relationship does NOT have a direction, in order to avoid bi-directional patterns in case n and m arrive in different order.

Comment: The question is: What happens when the `MERGE (n)-[:is_friends_with]-(m)` arrives before `MERGE (m:Person {id:bar})`? This is scenario that we are facing because we have no control over the order of the events.

Comment: Is that a realistic scenario? I mean, a relationship cannot exist without persons at the beginning and the end. In other words, the relationship includes always data that defines the start and end nodes. You should be able to extract that, in order to MERGE them first, so you can be sure that they exist before you MERGE the relationship.

Comment: When we ingest the data via `neo4j-streams` this is a normal scenario. An empty DB should be populated with the events from a Kafka topic. And it is a `stream`, that means it has no defined end. So we can not say: first import the `nodes` and afterwards the `relationships`.